# How to send emails to all emails in two separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now my query is:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpEmail(    
              vinID INTEGER,
              broID INTEGER,
              emailaddress VARCHAR(2500),
              emailReports BIT
              )      


       INSERT INTO #tmpEmail(vinID, broID, emailaddress, emailReports)
       SELECT DISTINCT vinID, broID, 
              CASE broID WHEN 0 THEN vin_emailaddress ELSE bro_emailaddress END,
              --CASE broID WHEN 0 THEN vin_emailReports ELSE bro_emailReports END,
              vin_emailReports
       FROM #tmp LEFT OUTER JOIN scan_vendorInfo 
                     ON vinID = vin_vinID
              LEFT OUTER JOIN scan_broker
                     ON broID = bro_broID


select * From #tmpEmail

drop table #tmpEmail
```

and I am trying to send an email to all people; if there is an email address in table vin and/or bro.
If there is only an email in one or the other, then just send it to that one.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Look this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/union.html

Comment: Try use Set operators (UNION / UNION ALL)

Comment: also, limit that varchar to something reasonable. 2500 is way too many chars for an email address and it just gives a boost to possible injections